# Copy data from one region to another within google cloud platform

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two table in two different region one in US east and another in AU west. I want to copy data from AU to US region into a table.
any suggestion how i can do that

Answer (score 0):

Use the dataset copy service to copy the dataset from AU to US.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets